# SQL Server GROUP BY that include column in SELECT but not in GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, database, database-administration

Please help me to solve this.

I have this table note:
[Notes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/615a5/12/0)

I want only this display:
[Highest note strength value, only 1 display if more than 1 same note strength value of distinct SubjectID and Stat](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70112/1/0)

The problem is there were notes that have the same note strength value.

Comment: Sorry for the long code snippet, I can't upload images because of low reputation. Thanks!

Comment: The reason low reputation users aren't allowed to upload images is precicely that. We are programmers here, we prefer long winded code to an image any day. An image is NOT worth a thousand dwords used to encode it.

Comment: However next time, you can try http://sqlfiddle.com/ to share your SQL

Comment: Those giant blocks of HTML and CSS have no relevance to why your SQL fails.

Comment: Thanks Guys, just trying to illustrate the table notes and results I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT ID,SubjectID,Stat,MAX([Note Strength Value]) AS [Note Strength Value]     FROM dbo.Note WHERE SeasonContext = 2015 AND Days in (99999, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 77777, 88888) GROUP BY SubjectID,Stat)`

Change to

`SELECT ID,SubjectID,Stat,MAX([Note Strength Value]) AS [Note Strength Value]     FROM dbo.Note WHERE SeasonContext = 2015 AND Days in (99999, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 77777, 88888) GROUP BY SubjectID,Stat,ID)`

always include the fields you select when using Group By.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n.ID
,n.SubjectID
,dbo.udf_StripHTML(ISNULL(n.Note,'')) AS [Note]
,n.[Note Strength Value]
FROM dbo.[Note] n INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID,SubjectID,Stat,MAX([Note Strength Value]) AS [Note Strength Value]
 FROM dbo.Note
 WHERE SeasonContext = 2015 AND Days in (99999, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 77777, 88888)
 GROUP BY ID,SubjectID,Stat) m  --added id in the group by clause
 ON n.ID = m.ID
WHERE n.SubjectID = 14463
ORDER BY n.[Note Strength Value] DESC
```

You can't select a column when you are using a aggregate function without specifying a `group by` on that column.

Comment: Thanks, @vkp. Just trying to show the table and results I wanted since I can't able to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution.

```
WITH Note_Max AS
(
    SELECT  ID, SubjectID, Stat, 
            MAX([Note Strength Value]) AS [Note Strength Value]
     FROM   dbo.Note
     WHERE  SeasonContext = 2015 AND 
            Days in (99999, 7, 14, 30, 60, 90, 77777, 88888)
     GROUP BY SubjectID,Stat
)

SELECT  n.ID
        ,n.SubjectID
        ,dbo.udf_StripHTML(ISNULL(n.Note,'')) AS [Note]
        ,n.[Note Strength Value]
FROM    Note n 
INNER JOIN
        n.ID = Note_Max.ID
WHERE   n.SubjectID = 14463
ORDER BY n.[Note Strength Value] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gehan. I've tried your code but returns error in this line: n.ID = Note_Max.ID.

Comment: GROUP BY ID, SubjectID,Stat
I think this should work, reason is you cannot ignore columns when you use  GROUP  clause.

Comment: Thanks, I've inlcuded the ID in group by clause but same results as the table. By the way the ID is unique.